# with the new iOS 11 coming out- does WebRTC support mean that Twilio will work for voice in a browser instead of an app?

Tags: safari, webrtc, mobile-safari, ios11

I have built a site that uses Twilio for voice and chat.
We want to be able to be utilized on a smart phone in the browser (Safari?), but iOS hasn't supported WebRTC in Safari yet.
The announcement says iOS 11 will have WebRTC support and Safari will also support it.

I saw lots of pre-iOS11 conversations, but not real examples yet.
Any thots?
Examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Twilio's repo (issue [#122](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/122)):

> Date posted: Aug 14, 2017
>
> We've released twilio-video.js@1.2.1 today with **experimental support for Safari 11**. We're calling this "experimental support" because, currently, Safari only supports the H.264 video codec and not VP8. This means most browser-based P2P Room applications should work fine, since most browsers ship H.264; however, you may have issues in P2P Rooms containing a mixture of browser- and mobile-based Participants. This is because Twilio's current iOS and Android Video SDKs aren't shipping H.264 yet (it's coming very soon). We also aren't advertising H.264 support in Group Rooms yet, so Safari-based Participants will not be able to share video in Group Rooms.

Comment: Nathan
Thank you. My current app is only Voice and SMS.
Where does that leave me?